# How can I get the drive letter of an ISO I mount with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have been working on an auto-installer as I have to reinstall Windows a lot, one of the software I install is Visual Studio 2013 which comes as an ISO.

I have written some code that mounts the ISO, but I can't work out how to return the drive letter for when I run the setup.

```
else if (soft == "Visual Studio 2013 Pro")
            {
                var isoPath = Loc.path + Loc.vs2013pro;
                using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.AddCommand("Mount-DiskImage").AddParameter("ImagePath", isoPath).Invoke();
                }
                var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Loc.path + Loc.vs2013pro);
                proc.WaitForExit();
                System.IO.File.Copy(Loc.path + @"\Visual Studio 2013 Pro\Serial.txt", folder + "/Serials/VS2013Pro Serial.txt");
            }
```

Comment: Using Powershell, you should just be able to do this: `(Get-Volume).DriveLetter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `PassThru` parameter, this causes a [`MSFT_DiskImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh830494.aspx) to be returned. The `DevicePath` property has the mount point in it.

Comment: DevicePath comes up empty/null for me using:
`var command = ps.AddCommand("Mount-DiskImage");
               command.AddParameter("ImagePath", isoPath);
                command.AddParameter("PassThru");
 foreach(PSObject psObject in command.Invoke()){
                    var path = psObject.Members["DevicePath"].Value;
                }`

Answer (score 1):

The marked answer doesn't work for me so based on a blog post I found on [PowerShell ISO mounting & unmounting](https://rcmtech.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/powershell-mounting-and-dismounting-iso-images-on-windows-server-2012-and-windows-8/) I decided to code this up as a good example using C# (required references System.Management.Automation &
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces).

```
        string isoPath = "C:\\Path\\To\\Image.iso";
        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {

            //Mount ISO Image
            var command = ps.AddCommand("Mount-DiskImage");
            command.AddParameter("ImagePath", isoPath);
            command.Invoke();
            ps.Commands.Clear();

            //Get Drive Letter ISO Image Was Mounted To
            var runSpace = ps.Runspace;
            var pipeLine = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
            var getImageCommand = new Command("Get-DiskImage");
            getImageCommand.Parameters.Add("ImagePath", isoPath);
            pipeLine.Commands.Add(getImageCommand);
            pipeLine.Commands.Add("Get-Volume");

            string driveLetter = null;
            foreach (PSObject psObject in pipeLine.Invoke())
            {
                driveLetter = psObject.Members["DriveLetter"].Value.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Mounted On Drive: " + driveLetter);
            }
            pipeLine.Commands.Clear();

            //Unmount Via Image File Path
            command = ps.AddCommand("Dismount-DiskImage");
            command.AddParameter("ImagePath", isoPath);
            ps.Invoke();
            ps.Commands.Clear();

            //Alternate Unmount Via Drive Letter
            ps.AddScript("$ShellApplication = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application;" + 
                "$ShellApplication.Namespace(17).ParseName(\"" + driveLetter + ":\").InvokeVerb(\"Eject\")");
            ps.Invoke();
            ps.Commands.Clear();
        }
```